# Get JSON data type from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, types

Evening everyone!

So, I have with me a JSON string...

```
{"username":"87db3983285d395ca0af9f","password":"f4f0bb1533ef5034ce6b0a8a7c49a43b","email":"xxx@gmail.com","hnum":3,"splicenum":22,"reg_ip":"71.126.122.217","reg_date":1364175245,"cur_ip":"71.126.122.217","ip_array":["71.126.122.217"],"logins":[],"about":""}
```

And I decode this string into an associative array in PHP using json_decode().

What I'm doing is trying to make 1 single function for querying a JSON object that has been converted to an associative array in PHP. For this function, I am now working on editing/updating fields.

Example:

```
json_edit(array(
    "set"=>array(
        "email"=>"yyy@yahoo.com"
    )
));
```

The key "set" means setting the value of a string or boolean. 
Another key would be "push" to append to an array, or "delete" to delete a string or an array.

What I'm wondering is, how can I get the data type of the current array part in PHP?

Meaning, how can I get PHP to say, "OK, the field 'username' is a string, and 'ip_array' is an array"?

I don't want to be able to "set" a string value to what is SUPPOSED to be just a boolean, or, an array.

Is there any way to get the JSON data types in PHP?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Do you not know the format of the JSON coming in ahead of time?

Comment: I do, but just for the sake of security, this would be nice.

Comment: By the way, I may also want to allow users for my website to use this on files that they host or own within their directory, and for those who may not understand JSON 100%, this would be good because if they try to set the value incorrectly for a specific type, then I can give them an error message saying what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about gettype(). Gettype() will return the data type of any variable. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: Yeah, I just found a few hours after I posted this question. Couldn't find it before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this;

```
<?php
function json_edit($json, $changes = array()){

    $decoded = json_decode($json);

    foreach($changes as $action => $data){
        swith($action){
            case 'SET':

                foreach($data as $key => $value){
                    $decoded[$key] = $value;
                }

            break;

            case 'DELETE' :

            break;
            default;

        }
    }

    return json_encode($decoded);
}
?>
```

Comment: This is nice, but the only reason why I prefer my method over this is because I feel that it's easier to read and write.

Also, I don't understand how this differentiates between the data types. (If it's supposed to.)